# Why was I downvoted?

Tags: discussion, voting

I don't care about the rep, and I know that downvotes can be somewhat random and sometimes undeserved, but In the early stages of a site, it's easy to go against the rules without knowing, so I would like to know if I violated a rule or something.

What wrong with [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2/99-bottles-of-beer/169#169)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get downvoted if your program is incorrect---which indeed was the case for your linked post.

Comment: Funny, on my machine, the output is correct.

Comment: @John: No, you misread the question. :-)

Comment: Oh, drat.  I guess I'm deleting that until I find time to fix it.  Thanks!